# How to Load type from string directly into linq expression in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, string, lambda, types

This is the definition:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult>(this IEnumerable source);
```

How to replace TResult with something like:

```
Type.GetType("MyClass from assembly");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Generic arguments enforce type security at compile time while the `Type.GetType` uses reflection and is not known at compile time. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Does it mean that I have to iterate through the collection manually and look at their types with typeof ?

Comment: You can't use `typeof` because it expects you to pass a value which is known at compile time. You could probably use a non strongly typed collection but once again, what are you trying to do? You talk about iterating over a collection. What collection? Give some more details.

Comment: I'm trying to do ISite.Container.Components.OfType<A>().First<A>() .. and A resides in another project / assembly. And I cannot add reference to that project.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this at compile time if you don't know the type involved, but you could write your own extension method for IEnumerable:

```
public static IEnumerable OfType(this IEnumerable source, Type t)
{
    foreach(object o in source)
    {
        if(t.IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType()))
            yield return o;
    }
}
```